# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm trying make online a project but there is an error i can't solve myself.
I already installed django but the server give me this error.
Virtualenv is also active.

```html
2017-09-25 20:10:27,471: ***************************************************
2017-09-25 20:10:30,892: Error running WSGI application
2017-09-25 20:10:30,893: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2017-09-25 20:10:30,893:   File "/var/www/asd1_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
2017-09-25 20:10:30,893:     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2017-09-25 20:10:30,893: ***************************************************
2017-09-25 20:10:30,893: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2017-09-25 20:10:30,894: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2017-09-25 20:10:30,894: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2017-09-25 20:10:30,894: ***************************************************
```

Wsgi file is it:

```
    import os
import sys


path = '/home/asd1/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Hosting is pythonanywhere.com

Comment: Is django installed in the env you're using? The error is due to django not being properly installed, so it's hard to debug without access to your system.

Comment: Quote from the error message: "If you're seeing an import error and don't know why, _we have a dedicated help page to help you debug_". Have you visited that help page?

Comment: Yes I visited the help page but it not explain my error.
@JeremyMcGibbon when I attempt to reinstall django in the virtualenv it says that it is already installed...

20:34 ~/mve $ pip install django

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install Django. You may have forgotten to install it while the environment was active.

You can learn how to do this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/install/).

This also could be because you have called your project a name such as "django" which would conflict with the installed packages.

Comment: I should unistall django first then reinstall it correctly... but how to uninstall it? When I do "pip uninstall django" it says denied permission...

Comment: You have to activate your virtualenv first: `source PATH_TO_ENV/bin/env`

Comment: the command to activate virtualenv in pythonanywhere is: ". ENVNAME/bin/activate" from the root. :)

Comment: Just to add to this- on PythonAnywhere, for a webapp, you should set the virtualenv in the webapp configs, and it will automatically activate it for you when the webapp is run. You do not need to activate it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The error means Django is not installed. You can install Django with the following command

```html
python -m pip install Django
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be answered many times, but recently I upgraded my ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10, and without changing any other thing, my running django server stopped running with this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`. I repeated the same install, `python3 -m pip install django` and it didn't help. Finally somebody else told me to use

`sudo python3 -m pip install django`

because I run the server with `sudo python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`, which actually worked for me.

Comment: It's not relevant to PythonAnywhere hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instruction on how to edit your wsgi? From the help page:

**Edit your WSGI file**

One thing that's important here: your Django project (if you're using a recent version of Django) will have a file inside it called wsgi.py. This is not the one you need to change to set things up on PythonAnywhere -- the system here ignores that file.

Instead, the WSGI file to change is the one that has a link inside the "Code" section of the Web tab -- it will have a name something like /var/www/yourusername_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py or /var/www/www_yourdomain_com_wsgi.py.

Comment: I know I have to edit the right wsgi, not that in the project folder :)

Comment: This would be a lot better with a link to the help page.