# why do I receive an error when I want to start my django app?

Tags: python, django

When I start my dajngo app with the "manage.py runserver" command, I receive the mistake :

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in 
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`
```

However, I've just verify the installation of all requirements, and my virtual environment is well activated. So I don't know why it's not working.

Thank for all of your answers !

Comment: You might need to run `python manage.py runserver`. Otherwise, can you provide output from `pip freeze`

Comment: what happens if you just run python, and then 'import python'?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv ? If so, is it "activated" ? In both case make sure django is installed, you can try `pip install django` or if you have a `requirements.txt` file, `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: after you activated venv, can you please type python --version

Comment: @mattyx17 I tried to type just `python manage.py runserver` but it was the same think, and here is the provide of the `pip freeze` : `apturl==0.5.2
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.7.0
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==2.8
cupshelpers==1.0
dbus-python==1.2.16
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.5.0
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
Django==2.2
django-debug-toolbar==1.11`

Comment: @mattyx17 : `django-extensions==2.1.6
entrypoints==0.3
httplib2==0.14.0
idna==2.8
keyring==18.0.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
louis==3.12.0
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
netifaces==0.10.4
oauthlib==3.0.1
olefile==0.46
pexpect==4.6.0
Pillow==7.0.0
protobuf==3.6.1
pycairo==1.16.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
PyGObject==3.36.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyRFC3339==1.1
python-apt==2.0.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz==2018.9
pyxdg==0.26`

Comment: @mattyx17 : `PyYAML==5.3.1
reportlab==3.5.34
requests==2.22.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
ubuntu-advantage-tools==20.3
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.25.8
wadllib==1.3.3
xkit==0.0.0
zope.interface==4.7.1`

Comment: @Roy2012 it happens this : `(simpletrainer_venv) robin@RobinPC:~/Documents/programmation/simpletrainer$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'`

Comment: @abrunet it's exactly what I did

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic when type `python --version`, I receive : `Python 3.8.2`

Comment: oops - I meant of course 'import django'. Apologies.

Comment: @Roy2012 it doesn't matter. When I type `import django` I receive :  ̀Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

Comment: @RobinJoseph you seem to have a quite old version of django. Try `pip install import django --upgrade`

Comment: @mattyx17 when I type `pip install import django --upgrade`, I receive : `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement import (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for import`

Comment: @RobinJoseph sorry my mistake `python -m pip install django --upgrade`.

Comment: @mattyx17 Sorry, but pip seems not work. I tried your proposal, or with python3 or with pip3, but I get always the same message : `No module named pip`. I don't know if it's really useful but i tried also `sudo apt-get install pip` and pip3, but nothing is working

Comment: @RobinJoseph It should be `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` or `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Answer (score 0):

can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46413719/11943384).

You need to install Django. You may have forgotten to install it while the environment was active.

Comment: thank for your answer, but it isn't this, because when I try to install django, I receive an error saying that django is already installed, and when I go to the 'site-packages' folder in the environment, there is a folder named django and another named Django-2.2.dist-info, with an '__init__.py' file in each.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command on terminal to install Django:

```
pip install Django
```

After this, run your project.

Comment: nothing is changing with this command because django is already installed : `Requirement already satisfied: Django in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Django) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Django) (0.3.0)`