# I can't find Django

Tags: django

After greeting . kindly help me to fix this error below

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in main
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 12, in main
        raise ImportError(
```

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413676/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that you have installed the latest version of Django, just type `pip install Django.

- If you do this outside a virtual environment, you must check that the python interpreter is in the System path settings, which you can read more [for Windows](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/), [for Mac](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac), and [for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002214/how-to-add-python-path-in-ubuntu-16-04) .
- If you do this within a virtual environment, remember to activate it. Again, there are many helpful resources online, covering [Windows, Mac, and Ubuntu](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/).

After this, you can test your installation by typing

```
$ django-admin help
```

If something shows up, then it means your edits are successful. If the terminal throws error, it means that you might've missed some steps in the middle.